# How do I design a svelte component to be available in multiple projects?

Tags: typescript, package.json, composition, svelte

I'm building two web applications in svelte/typescript:

- Site A that works as the public-facing front that needs to be as fast and lean as possible
- Site B that is the administration UI where editors update the content that is presented in Site A

I want to use the same "view component" (from Site A) in the editor (in Site B) but attach some editor logic in order to build a WYSIWYG experience without code duplication.

I could of course just make both Site A and Site B be part of the same svelte application but I don't want the visitors of Site A to load all the modules and code used in Site B.

How should I design this to avoid code duplication but still prevent logic from Site B from leaking into Site A?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best solution for that is to create a [design system](https://www.invisionapp.com/inside-design/guide-to-design-systems/):

> A design system is a collection of reusable components, guided by clear standards, that can be assembled together to build any number of applications.

The implementation is nothing more that creating a npm package. First you will create your design-system repo that contain all your components (`Button`, `Card`, ...). Then you will export all of them in a `index.js` file:

```js
export { Button } from 'path/to/component/Button';
export { Card } from 'path/to/component/Card';
...
```

Then you bundle your design-system and create a npm package which has the generated `index.js` file as entry.

Then in your different app you import the components from this package:

```js
import { Button } from 'my-design-system';
```

Comment: Good info. While I was learning about design system I found this article. It explains more about folder structures and index.js: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-index-js-public-interfaces

Comment: I'd prefer to access the ts files directly and not to use a build step in between, generating sourcemaps and symlinking and so on. So I'll start out with grohjy's answer first and see how far that takes me :-)

Comment: @ChristerCarlsund It will be enough until you want that someone else work on your project ;)

Comment: I believe you should go with @johannchopin ’s way. Making a npm package is pretty easy process and that way you “must” decide, which components are ready for publishing. I believe you can keep published and work-in-process components under the same “shared”-folder, but each of them should have it’s own folder. Now you can develop new components and when they are ready just move them to published folder and update you package. The package makes it easy to use these components in different projects. You just need to ‘npm install your_package’ and you’re ready to use you shared component.

Answer (score 4):

Let’s say you have an individual project folders for A and B, then you place shared components into a shared-folder, which is sibling to A and B.
When you import shared component to A you just give the import a correct path like `../shared/Comp.svelte`. And when you build your project, bundle.js will include only components, that are needed and nothing else.